# Symfony - can't run created console command

Tags: php, symfony

I've created a file called GenerateRandomUserCommand.php inside vendor/symfony/console/Command. Its namespace is set to: Symfony\Component\Console\Command it extends Command aswell. Clean composer and Symfony installation. The problem is, I can't make command working. I write: php bin/console mycommand (it is set of course in class) and I have a message: Command "mycommand" is not defined.

What's the problem? I did nothing in kernel or config, everything is default.

Comment: Why would you create a command under the vendor directory?  Are you using the Symfony framework or just the console component?

Comment: You should never write in vendor. Those files will be changed with a composer update and as a best practice are not checked into your git repository. You should keep your command in the src/ folder. The name of the file and the class name (besides the namespace) looks fine too. Do you extend the `Command` base-class? Does it list your command under a different name when calling `bin/console list`?

Answer (score 0):

It's need to see that not working command file. But I can suggest to you use symfony maker bundle.
First, require bundle for dev env: `composer require maker --dev`
Then simply type in console `bin/console make:command`. After typing name it was generate command skeleton with some simple example. And I beleive that's all you need =)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was, I must register command. Despite of autoregistering provided by Symfony...